# JavaScript event target

Tags: javascript, events, target

I have problem with event target. I want to check which element were clicked but it don't work. What is the solution this problem ?

```js
var prod = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function dodaj(e) {
    var tar = e.target;
    
    console.log(tar);
}


for(var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
    prod[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       dodaj(); 
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Try: prod[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       dodaj(e); 
    }, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your click event handler was an anonymous function that was putting in a call to the actual function that does the work (`dodaj`) and that function was not receiving the reference to the event - the anonymous function was.

You can change the anonymous function so that it receives the event and then passes it to `dodaj` like this:

```
prod[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
   dodaj(evt); 
}, false);
```

However, since that "wrapper" function really wasn't adding any value to your code, you can/should remove it entirely and just register the actual callback function as the click event handler.

```js
var prod = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function dodaj(e) {  
    console.log(e.target);
}

for(var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
  // When any button gets clicked, call the dodaj function
  // directly. This is the function that will receive a 
  // reference to the click event.
  prod[i].addEventListener("click", dodaj);
}
```

```html
<button id="one">Click Me</button>
<button id="two">Click Me</button>
<button id="three">Click Me</button>
<button id="four">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't passed anything into `dodaj`. You could just pass `dodaj` directly into `addEventListener`.

```
prod[i].addEventListener("click", dodaj, false);
```